# Отследить безопасное извлечение флешки

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, usb

Как на винде отследить событие безопасного извлечения устройства (флешки)? Эти WinAPI сообщения содержат только вставку/удаление https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/wm-devicechange, ни одно из них не тригерится, когда надо. Надо перехватить сообщение о попытке безопасного удаления ещё до удаления. Желателен python API.

Надо это для того, чтобы предотвратить ошибку "this device is currently in use", т.е. моя программа пишет на флешку, получает сообщение, что пользовать хочет сделать безопасное извлечение, перестаёт писать, теперь можно безопасно извлечь.

Как вариант, можно попробовать перехватить эту ошибку, а не безопасное извлечение.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27620273

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1315721/456123